# Representing seasonal calendar data

Tags: r

I am quite new R user and working on my data these days. I want to represent the seasonal occurrence of diseases in seasonal calendar (either circle or straight).

Data looks like this:

```
Diseases: Occurrence
A: Jan, Feb,March.
B: Apr, May, Dec.
C: July, Aug.
D: All year.
```

Please suggest possible ways of representing such data in R.
Thank you
AG

Comment: I think we will need more information. Can you show us parts of the data e.g. by using head(data)?

Comment: Thanks @JAQuent, I have data in an excel file yet. The data is almost the same as I have already given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... if I understand correctly, for each month you have only binary values, either the illness it's there or not.

If so, the below code may provide an indicative solution:

```
library("tidyverse")
data <- tribble(~Month, ~Disease1, ~Disease2, ~Disease3,
  1, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
  2, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,
  3, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  4, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  5, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  6, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  7, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  8, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  9, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
  10, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
  11, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  12, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)  

data %>% 
gather(Disease, Present, 2:ncol(data)) %>% 
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = factor(Month), y = Disease, color = Present)) +
geom_point()
```

[image: Example]

You can then customise this to your liking.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its almost the same what I am looking for. But when I replaced the disease1,2,3 with my own disease names, its giving that the object Disease does not exists.

Comment: it's probably related to the line with "gather":
gather(Disease, Present, 2:4) %>% 
If you have 3 diseases, it must be 2:4, if you have 4, 2:5, if you have 5, 2:6 and so forth

Comment: I also think so. Please see the following data. (~Month, ~FMD, ~HS, ~BQ,
  1, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
  2, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,
  3, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  4, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  5, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  6, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  7, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  8, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  9, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
  10, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
  11, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
  12, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE

Comment: I updated the answer to prevent this error, hope it works

Comment: Actually, with you data it works for me. make sure you have tribble before the parenthesis, and you close parenthesis after your last TRUE

Comment: sorry to bother you again: Error in factor(Month) : object 'Month' not found

Comment: with your data, it works for me. Have you changed the name of the first column? post your exact code, and I'll tell you what's wrong

Comment: data <- tribble(~Month, ~Anthrax, ~ BQ, ~FMD,
                1, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,  
                2, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,  
                3, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,  
                4, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
                5, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                6, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
                7, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,  
                8, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,  
                9, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) %>%
  data %>%
  gather(Disease, Present, 2:ncol(data)) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = factor(Month), y = Disease, color = Present)) +
  geom_point()

Comment: you were almost  there (it's two separate commands):

data <- tribble(~Month, ~Anthrax, ~ BQ, ~FMD, 1, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 2, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 3, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 4, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 5, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 6, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 7, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 8, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 9, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)

data %>% gather(Disease, Present, 2:ncol(data)) %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = factor(Month), y = Disease, color = Present)) + geom_point()

Comment: Really appreciate your time and effort for helping me. Regards.